# Trying to create a 555 timer but nothing shows up in my transient analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, multisim

[image]

I'm trying to learn more about 555 timers but my transient analysis renders me this empty graph. Is there something wrong with the way I am setting up my MultiSim Circuit?

Comment: Um, you do understand that OUT is shorted to return, yes? What do you expect to see?

Comment: Really dumb of me but got it to work after fixing that output. Thanks!